# Erro on AtmelStudio7.0 "avr/io.h"

Tags: c, atmelstudio

I got an error which says "avr/io.h: No such file or directory"
Please give me some advices.

---

```
#include "sam.h"
#include <avr/io.h>


int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize the SAM system */
    SystemInit();

    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using gcc-avr to compile?

Answer (score 0):

A correct installation should not give you that error.
What kind of project did you create? Are you using the correct toolchain?

You can try it manually in a terminal by running:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=<your proc> <myfile>.c -o <myfile>.elf
```

Assuming you have avr-gcc in your PATH.

You might also try reinstalling atmel studio